# SOLVED - How to create a Stripe Payment Link through just Python?

Tags: python, import, stripe-payments

Edit: the answer is in the comments.

I need to create Stripe payment links using Stripe's API in Python so they could be put into invoices. I have a code that creates Checkout Sessions and they work, but they expire in a short time and I need the links to be valid for at least a month or even more (that is why I am trying to create a Payment Link). I thought that I could just use the payment_link.py module, but it does not work, somehow the import is not valid. And also I hate how I need to specify the successful and unsuccessful URL with the Checkout Session.

The Checkout Session code that was working:

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = 'my_stripe_key'


def add_price_to_product(
        product_id,
        price
):
    price = stripe.Price.create(
        unit_amount=price,
        currency='eur',
        product=product_id,
        recurring=None,
    )

    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[{
            'price': price.id,
            'quantity': 1,
        }],
        mode='payment',
        success_url='https://large-type.com/#Successful%20payment%2C%20have%20a%20nice%20day!',
        cancel_url='https://large-type.com/#Payment%20cancelled%2C%20try%20again.'
    )

    return session.url



print(add_price_to_product(product_id='prod_XXXXXXX', price=1554))
```

The code that I was trying to use

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = 'my_stripe_key'


def add_price_to_product(
        product_id,
        price
):
    price = stripe.Price.create(
        unit_amount=price,
        currency='eur',
        product=product_id,
        recurring=None,
    )

    payment_link = stripe.PaymentLink.create(
        line_items=[{
            'price': price.id,
            'quantity': 1,
        }],
    )

    return payment_link.url



print(add_price_to_product(product_id='prod_XXXXXXX', price=1554))
```

Even though I see that inside the stripe folder exists a payment_link.py module, it does not import correctly.

I saw official documentation on https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/api and https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_links/payment_links/object

[image: How the failing import looks in PyCharm]

Comment: Turns out the problem was incorrect module importing from a bad interpreter. After replacing the whole interpreter the problem was fixed and the code worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would recommend against this approach since Payment Links are designed to be generated without code and be used multiple times. If you are generating them automatically, it is likely you need Stripe Checkout instead, since Payment Links are quite limited.

Checkout Sessions do expire quickly if you send the URL in an email or an invoice, so the best practice here is, to attach a link to *your own app* instead, with an invoice id, for example. When the customer clicks on the link, your application calls Stripe to generate a fresh Checkout Session specifically for this customer and redirects them to the Session URL. This way you don't need to worry about link expiry.

Alternatively, I recommend you to look at Stripe Billing, specifically Invoicing: https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/integration

Comment: Yea, I understand your point, but at this moment the invoices are just PDFs, so there is no way to make the Checkout Session generated when the link is pressed

Comment: The link in the PDF can be a URL to your own site. To the customer it will look like they just clicked on a link in PDF and landed on Stripe Checkout page. But under the hood, you first send them to your own server endpoint that generates the Session, and then it uses the Session URL to redirect them to Stripe Checkout.